# Geometry Nodes : is it possible to get the acceleration/speed of an attribute?

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

Is there a way to get the acceleration or speed of an attribute, for instance about the Z location of a point ?

Having this would permit to work on effects like bounces.

Thanks !

Comment: GN doesn't work with physics yet

Comment: I think that this is not really about physics.  An acceleration could be computed if we were able to, let's say, to get the value of something on the X last frames.

Comment: Just use the field at index node and calculate the location of the vertex/object from another frame, then you can subtract between e.g. loc(x) - loc(x+1) so you get the location difference. You know how many frames are between these location, so you will get the (average) speed which is (loc2 - loc1) / time_difference

Comment: You could "bake" the positions of each point into an array with python, create a path with this positions and use it in GN.

Comment: @quellenform etc  It would really open up GN if you could implement feedback/recursion, by modifying an incoming attribute, and stashing it back out as vertex-weights/colors.. refreshing per-frame. I've tried.. even with double-buffering. No luck.

Comment: Finally,it comes!!! We can do reaction-diffursion https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=-gIk_ZH4ySE